# Object properties not updated

Tags: javascript

I have an object with a function that updates the variables of the object. I would like to use this function as a constructor too, so I can define the properties inside it. If I only define the properties within this function other functions don't realize about the change.
I mean, this.property returns undefined.

The object looks like this:

```
    function LastRow_(sheet)
{
    var lastCol,firstRowVals,rowNumber,headers;
    this.rowValues;
    updateObject();

 // Logger.log(headers);
  /*Returns the value of a specific column within last row.
  It accepts header name or column letter in A1 notation*/
  this.getColValue=function(column)
  {
    updateObject();
    Logger.log(this.rowValues);
    var index=getColNumber(column);
    if(index>-1) return this.rowValues[index];

    Logger.log("Can't find header, trying with: "+column+rowNumber);
    return sheet.getRange(column+rowNumber).getValue();   

  };

  this.setColValue=function(column,value)
  {
     updateObject();

  };

  function getColNumber(colName){ return headers.indexOf(  colName.toLowerCase()  );  }

  /*This function is to be sure that you are allways working with the last row
  and an updated version of the headers*/
  function updateObject()
  {
    if(lastCol!==sheet.getLastColumn())
    {
        Logger.log("Updating row Headers");
        lastCol=sheet.getLastColumn();
        firstRowVals=sheet.getRange(1,1,1,lastCol).getValues()[0];
        headers=[];
        for(var i=0;i<firstRowVals.length;i++)
            headers.push(firstRowVals[i].toLowerCase());

        Logger.log(headers);
    }

    if(rowNumber!==sheet.getLastRow())
    {
      Logger.log("Updating row Values");
      rowNumber=sheet.getLastRow();
      this.rowValues=sheet.getRange(rowNumber,1, 1, lastCol).getValues()[0];
      Logger.log(this.rowValues);
    }


  };
}
```

Any call to the object methods produces the error

```
function test()   {/*valueLastRow(SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('workedDays'),"C",5)*/
  var LastRow=new LastRow_(SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('workedDays'));
  Logger.log(LastRow.getColValue("D"));
  Logger.log(LastRow.getColValue("sede"));
}
```

The problem is that this.rowNumber is undefined.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you share the code where you are seeing the unexpected behaviour? maybe that will help people understand the exact nature of your problem

Comment: Just a simple call to the object methods raises the error

Comment: Could you setup a JSFiddle?

Comment: you have `var lastCol,firstRowVals,rowNumber,headers;`  but you never specify a property of the object using `this.rowNumber` anywhere inside the object

Comment: @ekhaled I though in JS there were no need to declare variables first. Maybe this.rowNumber is pointing to a different object because that?

Comment: @Danielo515 you have to declare object properties in JS, you have declared `this.rowValues`, why not try declaring that too